# Spock ignore test if a "setup test" fail

Tags: testing, spock

I'm writing a kind of integration test. I need to test if the tested environments are actually running.

pseudocode:

```
def "setup test"() {
    expect:
    service1.isRunning()
    service2.isRunning()
}

def "test1"() {
    expect:
    service1.something() == 1
    service2.something() == 2
}

def "test2"() {
    // ...
}
```

Basically, I don't even want to see the results of "test1" and "test2" if the "setup test" fails (They will surely fail too!). How can I achieve this? I've tried `@IgnoreIf`, but it seems to be a solution only for conditions that we can provide from outside of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`@Stepwise`](http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Stepwise.html) annotation (defined at the class level) to achieve guaranteed order, and skip remaining tests if failure happens. Of course, the side effect is that if `test1` fails, `test2` won't be triggered, but that's the simplest way to introduce sequential and conditional execution.

> *Indicates that a spec's feature methods should be run sequentially in their declared order (even in the presence of a parallel spec runner), always starting from the first method. If a method fails, the remaining methods will be skipped. Feature methods declared in super- and subspecs are not affected.*
>
> `@Stepwise` is useful for specs with (logical) dependencies between methods. In particular, it helps to avoid consecutive errors after a method has failed, which makes it easier to understand what really went wrong.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Stepwise.html</sup>